# Two laptops not connecting via LAN cable

Tags: lan

I wanted to share my data between the two laptops and here is what I did in the following order:

1. Installed Realtek PCIe FE family controller on both the laptops.
2. Disabled firewalls completely over both the laptops.
3. Connected both the laptops via CAT.5E UTP cable with RJ-45 connector. In the connections, still was getting the cables unplugged.
4. Provided IP addresses 192.168.1.10 and 192.168.1.11 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0 on both.
5. Still it was displaying it unplugged, and then, created a home network on one laptop.
6. After doing this all, opened run and typed \ followed by the IP address of the another laptop.
7. After half a minute it would tell no response from another laptop with a diagnose option.
8. In Device Manager, Realtek PCIe FE family controller it is OK, but in addition to it, it displays a PCI device as unknown.

Why still in connections the cables are shown as unplugged, assuming that the OS on both the laptops is Windows 8.1, belong to same workgroup and the cable was checked beforehand and is alright.

Is there any compatibility issue with the driver?

Comment: When you post questions, please ensure it lays out correctly, it was a mess, but I've improved it a little. Are you trying to connect by a single cable, or are you plugging both into a router? Did you enable network discovery

Comment: Sorry, for the mess. I am using this website for the ver first time.  I was trying to connect by a single cable.

Answer (score 2):

The common RJ45 network cables are actually "**patch cables**". They are wired to connect a computer to a hub or a switch.

For connecting two computers directly to each other you need to use a "**crossover cable**". These are usually part of the network technician toolbox but not very common otherwise.

You may sometime find it in a computer shop or you can build it yourself with adequate tools and patience but it is just much simplier, and probably not much more expensive, to just have two regular network cables connecting you computers via a small passive network switch.

There is also a Microsoft support article on this topic here: [Connect two computers using a crossover cable](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ph/windows/connect-two-computers-crossover-cable)

Answer (score 0):

When setting up a direct connection, there are few things you should keep in mind:

- You have to use a [crossover cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) (unless at least one network adapter supports automatic detection of cable type).
- You have to leave the *Default gateway* field empty on first machine and fill it with first machine's IP on second one. Here's an example config:

  First machine:

  [image: Example config for first machine]

  Second machnie: (use this or enable *Obtain an IP address automatically*)

  [image: Example config for second machine]
- If you have IP settings configured manually, you have to provide DNS servers for Internet address resolution. You can use `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` (Google DNS) as illustrated above.

This setup should work, but you may experience some issues such as high packet loss with UDP connections.

Comment: The cable i used is CAT.5E UTP. Is there a difference amoung the cables used at cyber cafes to connect their PCs with each other via switch or router and the ethernet CROSSOVER cables that you mentioned before.

Comment: You probably have a *patch cable* which is used to connect NICs with routers or switches. The crossover cable has additional two pairs of wires *crossed*. You can identify your cable type by looking at colors of wires, [this article](http://blog.cablesandkits.com/2011/11/untangling-network-cable-types-2/) contains a useful connection schema.

Answer (score 0):

A CROSSOVER cable is the same CAT 5 UTP you have, but with a different combination of the internal pins.

You need to go to a store and ask for a Crossover LAN cable. The one you have needs a router, switch or hub between both machines.